# Date failing to update, but returning true for Update (Rails ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails model called user that has a birthday field with type date in Postgres.

My first issue is that I'm not sure how to update the value of a user. If I pass in a string like "10/10/1980", it does not update.

The second issue is that even when the birthday is not updated, Rails returns true for the User.update(user_params) action

My two questions:

1. How can I update a date field?
2. How can I make sure that rails throws an error if an incorrect date is passed in?

How can I update a date field?

Update method from controller below. Fairly standard from scaffolding.

```
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      puts(user_params)
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Edit: Params:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:points, :payment_option, :first_name, :last_name,
                  :payment_email, :phone_number, :facebook_id, :profile_pic_url,
                  :locale, :timezone, :gender, :email, :country, :city,
                  :age_group, :birthday, :employment_status, :occupation,
                  :education_level, :income_bracket)
  end
```

Rails log (note that I added a puts(user_params) after the update statement.

```
Started PATCH "/api/v1/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-07 19:16:37 +0800
Processing by UsersController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"birthday"=>"12dsafkljfsldk"}, "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
{"birthday"=>"10/10/1900"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering users/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendered users/_user.json.jbuilder (0.6ms)
  Rendered users/show.json.jbuilder (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 5.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

I was hoping that I could use `before_update` to parse the date string into a Date object before saving, but it doesn't look like self.birthday is even showing up in the model.

Comment: Try not to write "stringly typed" code. If you have a date, use the `Date` class. Not a string. Anyway, with that said -- *Why* doesn't it save? What does the rails log say? What is `@user.errors`? What behaviour are you seeing, exactly -- you say "it doesn't save" *and* "it doesn't throw an error"???!! According to your code, an error *will* be rendered if the record did not save!

Comment: The params are being passed in as a JSON body in an HTTP call from another server.

Comment: As for what I'm seeing. I'm seeing that @user.update(user_params) is returning true, so it's "saving" but @user.birthday is still blank. The user_params are making it to the call as {"birthday"=>"10-10-1900"}

Comment: did you permit the date in `user_params`?

Comment: @JCDJulian What's in the rails log? **Always** look at the log, when debugging. My guess - and this is only a guess, since your code sample above is incomplete (what is `user_params`?) is that the parameter is not *permitted*.

Comment: It's permitted. Was able to print it as well. Updated to show.

Comment: @JCDJulian ...And the rails log says?......

Comment: Editing the question with it.

Comment: And there you go: `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.`. **Always** look at the rails log! (Or frankly, the log of *any* application you're developing!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this line in your **ApplicationController**

```
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

If it doesn't work then. Try to skip the action

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```